Why did Peter Higgs, et al. suspect that the $W$ boson(s) had mass? All the way back in 1963, '64?
I cannot understand why so many people (the PRL Symmetry authors) were so sure that the weak interaction particles had mass.
The gluon, for instance, and its attendant strong force are also very short range, and the gluons can also interact with each other. Yet they are considered massless.

Yeah, but to propose a mechanism like confinement when a simpler explanation exists (massive particle) would be pretty crazy...

... I don't think we even had the notion of confinement in 1963/64...

Maybe try History of science and math SE

Already in 1957, Julian Schwinger, Annals of Physics 2 (5) November 1957, pp    407-434, "A theory of the fundamental interactions", had inferred from the chiral structure and puny strength of the weak interactions in  weak decays that there is likely an intermediate vector boson, a charged massive photon analog, intermediating these decays.

Indeed, that time scale becomes more comprehensible, without invoking inordinately weak interactions, if every observable process requires the virtual creation of a heavy particle. Our general viewpoint regarding the systematic reduction of internal symmetry also impels us to seek some internal symmetry aspect of the Z field that is destroyed by the coupling with various combinations of electrically charged and neutral fields. [...] One consequence of these assignments refers to the self-coupling of the lepton field through the intermediary of the Z field, which implies the physical process μ ⟶ e + 2ν.

His Z is, of course, $W^{\pm}$. He wasn't the first to speculate on that, an obvious conjecture over the decades of darkness since the advent of the underlying contact 4-Fermi theory (1933). Giving mass to photon-like vector particles had been a holy grail theory problem for decades.
At that time, people were deeply confused about the strong interaction and their structure, and wouldn't even dream about quarks, let alone what kept them together into hadrons!
I strongly suspect this is a question for HSM!

In 1961, Sheldon Lee Glashow already published his paper with the correct EW symmetry group SU(2)$\otimes$U(1) and hypothesized the W and Z bosons. The question, traced back to Julian Schwinger (Glashow's PhD thesis advisor) was how to give a mass to them, being Yang-Mills fields, without spoiling gauge invariance. Glashow inserted such mass terms by hand but gauge invariance requires zero mass and so, he spoiled it. The idea was to use breaking of spontaneous symmetry as Nambu and Jona-Lasinio proposed in 1960 (Y.N.) and 1961 (Y.N. and G.J.-L., here and here) but there was a difficult problem to overcome: A breaking of symmetry generates massless excitations known as Goldstone bosons never observed in nature. This was completely acquired after this paper by Weinberg, Salam and Goldstone in 1962. This set the stage for Higgs mechanism to come in the scene in 1964.
